# Getting "String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated" when inserting new record

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I get this error when I try to insert to the database. I already checked if the size was long enough and if the attributes where ok.
This is my SQL layout.

```
schoolID   int (Primary Key)
schoolNaam varchar(50)
stad       varchar(30)
```

My code for inserting:

```
BLSchool blSchool = new BLSchool();
List<School> scholen = blSchool.GetAll();
School school = new School();
school.SchoolNaam = schoolnaam.ToString();
school.Stad = schoolstad.ToString();
int schoolID = blSchool.InsertSchool(school);
db.Schools.InsertOnSubmit(school);
db.SubmitChanges();
return school.SchoolID;
```

Comment: This doesn't look like Classic ASP (VBScript or JScript).

Answer (score 0):

No, you didn't check the size or at least not properly. Either `schoolnaam` is more than 50 characters long, or `schoolstad` is more than 30.

To avoid that error, have such code:

```
school.SchoolNaam = new string(schoolnaam.ToString().Take(50).ToArray());
school.Stad = new string(schoolstad.ToString().Take(30).ToArray());
```

This will take only the first 50/30 characters in case the values are longer.

Comment: Better use substring from a helper method. This is really inefficient.

Comment: @usr this is the shortest way without adding extension or conditions. I doubt the ~nano second difference is so important.

Comment: Thanks mate. Using this code showed me what i did wrong. I needed to put schoolnaam.Text in order to make it work.
stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

A string is too long, you just didn't find the problem yet.

Probably you should just increase the column length. A `varchar` takes as much space as needed. It does not waste space to increase the size.

You also probably should validate the string on the client and show the user an error.

Don't just truncate it because that destroys data without notice to the user.